# iptables rules for machine running as openvpn server

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I set up an older laptop as an OpenVPN server for my home network (and a dwarffortress server, but that's beside the point).  This is the first time I've set something like this up - I wanted a secure way of being able to ssh into my home network from outside.

In any case, I got it working (finally figured out I needed to port forward 1194 on my router), but I wanted to make sure that I'm not opening up things in the wrong way.  Do these iptables-rules look reasonable?:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Dec 28 02:16:10 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3:517]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:517]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.88.0/24 -o wlp3s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Dec 28 02:16:10 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Dec 28 02:16:10 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [323:24107]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [152:13348]
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.88.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Dec 28 02:16:10 2014
```

Edit: Ok, here are my current rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Dec 29 03:36:02 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [14:2325]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:144]
-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i wlp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.88.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Dec 29 03:36:02 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Dec 29 03:36:02 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [389:94808]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:60]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:72]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1:72]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.88.0/24 -o wlp3s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Dec 29 03:36:02 2014
```

I can make SSH connections internal to my network (though it seems slower to connect/ask for password than before), but now I am unable to make an OpenVPN connection from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not enough to `ACCEPT` traffic on `tun` interface. You will also need to open
1194/udp port in `INPUT` chain.

```
-A INPUT -i wlp3s0  -j ACCEPT -m udp -p udp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

You should also setup a default policy for `INPUT` chain to `DROP`. Now you allow all incoming connections!

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [323:24107]
```

HTH

Comment: So is there a security hole the way I have it now?  I have been able to connect successfully to it.

Comment: Well, yes. It can be established any connection from outside world to your laptop. It is Ok as far as your router is guarding but if you take laptop outside, it would be better to setup firewall as I described.

Comment: So I should change `:INPUT ACCEPT [323:24107]` to `:INPUT DROP [323:24107]` and add `-A INPUT -i wlp3s0  -j ACCEPT -m udp -p udp --dport 1194 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT` after `-A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT`?

Comment: When I tried doing `iptables-restore` with the rules changed as above, I get a message `iptables-restore v1.4.21: multiple -j flags not allowed; Error occurred at line: 16`.

Comment: Remove first occurence of `-j ACCEPT`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Hmm...now internal SSH doesn't work though.  How do I allow for SSH connections within my home network?

`iptables -A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlp3s0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Well, I can connect internally now. But I don't seem to be able to make an OpenVPN connection anymore from outside.

Comment: First: `iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`. Second: `iptables -A INPUT -i wlp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work now.  THough I have two similar looking lines now: `-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i wlp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i wlp3s0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`. Do I need both?  Does it matter?

Comment: You can remove the first one.